# How to get valid class instance after doing a qmlRegisterType?

Tags: c++, qt, qt-quick

I am using Qt 5.7 on ios & android. I use call to `qmlRegisterType` to instantiate `MyClass` derived from `QQuickItem` view.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);
    qmlRegisterType<MyClass>("MyClass", 1, 0, "MyClass");
    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    QQmlContext* ctx = engine.rootContext();
    engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/qml/main.qml")));
    return app.exec();
}
```

How can I get a valid object of MyClass back from qml ?

Comment: For what would you need the objects of MyClass on the C++ side?
There might be better ways of achieving the same result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get access to the tree of objects instantiated by the QML code through the engine's root object(s), see `QQmlApplication::rootObjects()`

You can then traverse the QObject tree to find the object(s) you are looking for.

However, accessing objects instantiated in QML on the C++ side is very often just a hack for something that can be done in a better way.

The general rule of thumb is to avoid C++ code depending on QML code, i.e. avoid making the rather static C++ side depend on the way more dynamic QML side.

Prefer letting the C++ side provide data and functionality and letting the QML side consume that data and trigger/call the C++ functions.

Comment: Would be nice if you mentioned the other ways you could recommend in this example?

Answer (score 0):

In your code you registered MyClass QML custom object into the QML Objects Library. That would allow you instantiate your QML component *MyClass* in your QML documents like this:

```
import MyClass.1.0
Item {

.....
    MyClass{
    }
}
```

So registering QML objects will give you the possibility to instantiate your QML Objects like the one you mentioned in you sample code.

So if you want, to access any object from your QML "Scene" in any of your C++ classes you got load the Object Scene, and crawl through their children. Refer to this documentation:

[Interacting with QML Objects from C++](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-cppintegration-interactqmlfromcpp.html)

And you should be more than fine.

One more thing: I think the most common "first time ever" need when reading QML objects from C++ is to read a property, so in the link there's this section: "Accessing Members of a QML Object Type from C++". Go right there for a start.

Comment: Thanks for the pointers. It got me in the right direction for sure. I read through the section"Accessing Members of a QML Object Type from C++". understand that we can set a property into a qml item. `MyClass` here is derived from `QQuickitem`. And, I need to set another object instance to one of its setter method like so : `MyClassObject->SetOtherObjectInstance(*someOtherObject)` Is there any sample code which does the same kind of thing ? What I am doing is a not a rare requirement I believe

Comment: It is very rare to retrieve a pointer to a QML instantiate object from C++ as this creates a dependency from C++ to QML and restricts what the QML tree can look like.
If `MyClass` requires this `someOtherObject` to work, then it might be better if `MyClass` would retrieve that object instead